# Download Corresponding CA Root file for a certificate

Tags: ssl, openssl, x509certificate

I have successfully retrieved a intermediate certificate for a certificate:

```
openssl x509 -inform pem -noout -text -in cert.pem | 
          awk 'BEGIN {FS="CA Issuers - URI:"} NF==2 {print $2; exit}'
```

This gives:

http://certificates.godaddy.com/repository/gdig2.crt

Perfect, so I download that, and it is the intermediate certificate. Within that certificate, I see:

```
Issuer: C=US, ST=Arizona, L=Scottsdale, O=GoDaddy.com, Inc., 
        CN=Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
```

So this is the root certificate that is on my filesystem. How do I get `openssl` to show me the corresponding file for this? Or do I have to manually match it by name within `/etc/ssl/certs/` (in this case, `Go_Daddy_Root_Certificate_Authority_-_G2.pem`)...

I am essentially trying to output a chained certificate file up to the root CA.

Comment: Preferably, you can manually match-up the Intermediate CA's "Authority Key Identifier" with the Trusted Root CA's "Subject Key Identifier", because common name alone can sometimes yield duplicates (expired, etc).  Also, the Intermediate CA should have a "Certificate Policies" attribute containing a URL where the CA can be reviewed and downloaded from, if not found on the local system.  I am unaware of any OpenSSL commands to automate these matching and retrieval tasks.